# Add bound to class type parameter in method

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way how to make class type parameter more narrow (add another bound to it) in concrete method?

Let's look at example

```
public class Value<T>
{
    private final T value;

    public Value(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <V extends T> boolean eq(V value)
    {
        return Objects.equals(this.value, value);
    }

    // here, I want to create bound that T extends Comparable<T>
    // error: type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds
    public <V extends T & Comparable<T>> boolean gt(V value)
    {
        return ((V)this.value).compareTo(value) > 0;
    }

    // here, I want to create bound that T extends String
    // error: interface expected here
    public <V extends T & String> boolean match(V value)
    {
        return ((V)this.value).equalsIgnoreCase(value);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Value<Integer> integerValue = new Value<>(10);
        integerValue.eq(10);           // should compile
        integerValue.gt(5);            // should compile
        integerValue.match("hello");   // shouldn't compile because match operates only on String values

        final Value<String> stringValue = new Value<>("Foo");
        stringValue.eq("Foo");         // should compile
        stringValue.gt("bar");         // should compile
        stringValue.match("foo");      // should compile
    }
}
```

In this example line

```
integerValue.match("hello");
```

doesn't compile, which is correct, but the class can't be compile too due to restriction that **type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds**

Is there any other way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance method must be available to all instances of the class. You can't declare a method that only exists for some instances of the class, those with certain type parameters.

What you can do is make a generic static method that takes an instance of the class as an argument. Since the generic type parameter is now specific to the method, it can be restricted to what the method wants:

```
public static <T> boolean eq(Value<T> obj, T value)
{
    return Objects.equals(obj.value, value);
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean gt(Value<T> obj, T value)
{
    return obj.value.compareTo(value) > 0;
}

public static <T extends String> boolean match(Value<T> obj, T value)
{
    return obj.value.equalsIgnoreCase(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `&` operator assumes that `V` directly extends `T` and `String`, so one of them has to be an interface as a class can not directly extend two other classes. It doesn't work either for `Comparable<T>` as compilator can not garantee type safety with that typo.

You just have to use a `,` :

```
// here, I want to create bound that T extends Comparable<T>
// error: type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds
public <V extends T, T extends Comparable<T>> boolean gt(V value)
{
    return ((V)this.value).compareTo(value) > 0;
}

// here, I want to create bound that T extends String
// error: interface expected here
public <V extends T, T extends String> boolean match(V value)
{
    return ((V)this.value).equalsIgnoreCase(value);
}
```

Comment: I know, but this will introduce new T type parameter which hides class type parameter T and also the line with integerValue.match("hello") will compile now.

Comment: What about restricting in class declaration : class Value<T extends Comparable<T>> ?

Comment: I can't restrict the type in class declaration, because you can create a value of any type you want, but gt operation should compile only if your type extends Comparable<T>.

Comment: what about throwing an exception if T does not extend Comparable<T> before returning the boolean ?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I am doing right now. I just want to make sure that there is no other possible solution which is type safe.

Answer (score 0):

Type bounds aren't the solution you need. What you need are subclasses.

```
public class Value<T>
{
    protected final T value;

    public Value(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean eq(T value)
    {
        return Objects.equals(this.value, value);
    }
}

public class ComparableValue<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Value<T>
{
    public ComparableValue(T value)
    {
        super(value);
    }

    public boolean gt(T value)
    {
        return this.value.compareTo(value) > 0;
    }
}

public class StringValue extends ComparableValue<String>
{
    public StringValue(String value)
    {
        super(value);
    }

    public boolean match(String value)
    {
        return this.value.equalsIgnoreCase(value);
    }
}
```

Then `main` becomes

```
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final ComparableValue<Integer> integerValue = new ComparableValue<>(10);
        integerValue.eq(10);           // will compile
        integerValue.gt(5);            // will compile
        integerValue.match("hello");   // will not compile

        final StringValue stringValue = new StringValue("Foo");
        stringValue.eq("Foo");         // will compile
        stringValue.gt("bar");         // will compile
        stringValue.match("foo");      // will compile
    }
```

Comment: Thats what I was thinking about too. One drawback is that there could be operations that will be available in multiple subclasses and you can't inherit one from the another, so there would be a code duplication. Another drawback is, that client have to choose right subclass to use. In my situation there would be like ~10 subclasses, so it will be very annoying.

Comment: True, but I don't think there's any other way you are going to get compile-time checking.